# LINQ doesn't give output I expect

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio

```
 var CC = new List<Company>();

            Company t1 = new Company();
            t1.Comp = "ABC";
            t1.Area = "Area1";
            t1.Link = "https://www.google.com";
            CC.Add(t1);

            Company t2 = new Project();
            t2.Comp = "DEF";
            t2.Area = "Area2";
            t2.Link = "https://www.yahoo.com";
            CC.Add(t2);

            var a = from p in CC where p.Comp == "ABC" && p.Area == "Area1"
                    select p.Link;

Console.WriteLine(a);

            Console.Read();
```

In the above code I expect to see the output as "www.google.com".

But what I see is .

[image]

Where am I going wrong ?? and how can I see "www.google.com" ?

Comment: This is not LINQ to SQL. It is simple LINQ to Objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`a` is returning as `IEnumerable` if you want to access google then you'd like to `foreach` on it or do `FirstOrDefault()`

```
foreach(var item in a)
{
 Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

More information can be found [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=linq%20select&oq=linq%20select&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2391j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Another option is `Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\r\n", a));` or similar.

Answer (score 4):

As there is no way to know how many will match, your variable `a` is not a single match, but the list of matches. You will need to pick one, maybe the first:

```
Console.WriteLine(a.FirstOrDefault());
```